# I wonder whether it is the relative pronoun

Tags: superlative-degree, relative-pronouns

> Truth be told, I never graduated from college, and this is the closest I've ever gotten to a college graduation.

In this clip from Steve job's speech in Standford school, I wonder what is the part of "the closest"? Do I see it as the adjective, dropping the pronoun "one"?

I think it should be like this:

this is the closest **one (that)** I've ever gotten to a college graduation.

Right?

If that's the case, should I think "the closest" is basically the object of a verb "have gotten"?

Then, what is the meaning of "get" in here?

Comment: "the closest" is complement to subject. Just like hungry is in "I am hungry", or "this is the hungriest, I have ever been". _Get_ in your context means to "become"/"been"/"come"

Comment: What do you mean with "relative pronoun" in your headline? "the closest"  is a superlative formula.

Comment: @rogermue Yes, but it's modified by a relative clause, though. It's not unreasonable for us to look for a relative pronoun (even thought there isn't one!) :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Truth be told, I never graduated from college, and this is the closest I've ever gotten to a college graduation.

Almost, but not quite. This sentence does indeed involve a relative clause. We could reconstruct the relative clause like this:

- Truth be told, I never graduated from college, and this is the closest **that I've ever gotten to a college graduation.**

The important thing about relative clauses is that they have a gap in them. The gap tells us where the missing element should be. So for example consider this sentence:

- This is the man that [you saw yesterday].

This relative clause has a gap in it that tells you where *the man* would be in the clause:

- This is the man that [you saw ___ yesterday].

Because our language brain knows where the gap is we can understand the sentence like this:

- This is the man that [you saw **the man** yesterday].

**The relative clause**

It is not straightforward to understand exactly where the gap is here. This is because, as the Original Poster felt, we often associate relative clauses with a noun phrase antecedent. However, in this case the antecedent isn't a typical noun phrase. Here's where the gap is:

- this is the closest that [I've ever gotten ____ to a college graduation]

We understand it like this:

- this is the closest that [I've ever gotten **close** to a college graduation].

This sentence is unusual because it has a superlative adjective as an antecedent, not a noun or clause. The verb *gotten* her means something like *come* or *been*.

**The grammatical function of *closest***

The Original Poster asks if *the closest* is the Object of the verb *GET*, in this case part of the perfect construction *have gotten*. The answer is, no. However, it has a function similar to an Object. Like an Object, it is a Complement of the verb. But it is a Predicative Complement, not an Object. Like Objects, Predicative Complements fill a special slot set up by the verb. They don't tell us *what* someone was doing something to though and they don't introduce a new entity into the sentence. Instead Predicative Complements tell us something about the Subject or Object of the sentence.

In this case, the phrase  *the closest that I've ever got to a college graduation* is the Predicative Complement of the verb *is*. It describes the situation denoted by *this*. Notice that this is *NOT* an adverbial. It is not an extra part of the grammar in the sentence. It is not an extraneous addition to the meaning either. The sentence is quite simply ungrammatical without it:

> *Truth be told, I never graduated from college, and this is. (ungrammatical with this meaning)

The verb *BE* cannot ever, ever take Objects, it can only take Predicative or Locative Complements.

Comment: You suggest, 'This is the closest that I've ever gotten close to a college graduation.'  and that is how 'we' understand it. I disagree. I for one don't even understand what you intend it to mean. It is simply not an English sentence.

Comment: @chasly no, quite right, it's not an English sentence because the gap in the relative clause has been filled in! The only point there is that the relative clause has a gap that is indexed with *closest*. So it's something along the lines of "Out of all the times ***that I've come close to a college graduation***, this is the closest. (I Anglicised the *gotten* for you there). It's not perfect, but there you go!

Comment: Reading this again, I have a new insight - and a new answer. It's not far form your bolded clause. I'll be back!

Answer (score 0):

Consider

> This is closer than I've ever gotten to a college graduation.

Can we agree that in this sentence, *closer* is an adjective modifying *I*?

If we change "closer" to "the closest", I think we are still dealing with an adjective.

Comment: Have you gotten *close* to a college graduation, or have you gotten *closely* to a college graduation? Do you get *hungry* after hard work, or do you get *hungrily* from hard work? We can't agree; I think it's an adjective modifying *I*.

Comment: @PeterShor - Oh!  I think you're right.  I will edit my answer.  (Unless you want to write one, and then I'll delete mine.)

Comment: No. Go ahead and edit your answer.